# Equivalent of Shift+Alt+A of Eclipse in IntelliJ?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

The ***Toggle Block Selection Mode*** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) command in Eclipse let me select code/text from an area.

Is there something similar in IntelliJ?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't list that as a command in their [docs](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-keybindings.htm?cp=0_4_4_0_6), is it from a plugin?

Comment: What kind of computer are you using? Also you can change what you want any shortcut in the perferences.

Comment: @phaze0 No it is not from a plugin.

Comment: I change the question because there was a mistake

Comment: Out of curiosity - What would this be useful for in daily usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select area of code you are able to do that by **selecting it while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>**.

Comment: You can also do this (to a limited degree) using just the keyboard. Press `Ctrl` on Windows/Linux or `Alt` on Mac **twice** and **_hold_** the key down on the second press. Then use the arrow keys to make your selection. Release the modifier once your selection is made. Then make your edit. Very useful for making an edit on multiple lines. Finally, you can use `Alt`+`Shift`+ `Mouse Click` to create multiple edit points. Useful for editing disjointed lines.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes looking for this, it seems to actually be:

ALT + SHIFT + INSERT -> "Column Selection Mode"